# SQL Group by only if it satisfy a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query few users from a table joined to a bookings table but there are conditions to satisfy and I don't know how to get the expected results.

> Conditions

- Return unique users
- Only if lasts 3 completed bookings are eq to `notified is null`

> Tables

```
Users

id | name
---+-----
1  | Jonh
2  | Jim
3  | Jen

Bookings

id | user_id |    state    |        notified
---+---------+-------------+----------------------
12 | 1       | 'completed' | NULL
11 | 2       | 'completed' | NULL
10 | 3       | 'completed' | '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
9  | 1       | 'completed' | '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
8  | 2       | 'completed' | NULL
7  | 3       | 'completed' | NULL
6  | 1       | 'completed' | '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
5  | 2       | 'completed' | NULL
4  | 3       | 'completed' | NULL
3  | 1       | 'completed' | '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
2  | 2       | 'completed' | '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
1  | 3       | 'completed' | NULL
```

> Query a have so far

```
SELECT users.id, bookings.id, bookings.notified
FROM users
  JOIN bookings ON users.id = bookings.user_id
  WHERE bookings.state = 'completed'
GROUP BY users.id, bookings.id, bookings.notified
HAVING (bookings.notified IS NULL)
ORDER BY bookings.id DESC;
```

[Fiddle LINK](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cd846/1/0)

> Expected

```
user_id 
-------
2
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am expecting to get user id 2 as the result that is the only one that satisfies my filtering. From the last user completed bookings the range of last 3 should be `notified = null`

Comment: I don't understand this requirement "Only if lasts 3 completed bookings are eq to notified is null".  The last 3 means that they are comparable. But because they are NULL, they cannot be compared, and will typically come at the bottom of a `ORDER BY bookings.notified DESC`. By being NULL, they *can never be* among the last.

Comment: Is this postgres?

Comment: last three rows for user_id=3 has notified = null, why don't you expect user_id = 3?

Comment: @McNets is postgres

Comment: You are right @McNets, my mistake to write the booking sort order. Now the query will satisfy only the user 2 not user 3 anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns the users that you want:

```
SELECT b.user_id
FROM bookings b
WHERE b.id >= (SELECT b2.id
               FROM bookings b2
               WHERE b2.user_id = b.user_id AND b2.state = 'completed'
               ORDER BY b2.id DESC
               OFFSET 2 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
              ) AND
     b.state = 'completed'
GROUP BY b.user_id
HAVING COUNT(notified) = 0;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3720/9) is the SQL Fiddle.  Note this SQL Fiddle uses *Postgres* not *MySQL* (yours uses MySQL).

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The requirement needs a subquery - it cannot be done in a single shot.

Comment: Though, I do not follow what the OP means by this: "Only if lasts 3 completed bookings are eq to notified is null". Unless if by "last", he means the last three physical insertions and not a chronological "last" (which would not make sense for rows with the date field being NULL.

Comment: @luis.espinal I guess I didn't explain it right. What I mean is last 3 user bookings in a row. I am trying to get all users that didn't notify his book ending but I don't want to get those users that didn't notify his booking in his history, but only if his last 3 bookings he didn't notify the company.

if I apply null into a where it will ignore those bookings between nulls. I would like to have only if there is sequential of nulls and this sequential is equal user last bookings